# Gigaspaces: set directory with runtime dependecies for PUs

Tags: classpath, gigaspaces

My processing units have runtime dependencies and if I put them into $GigaSpaces_root/lib/required then my PUs deploys fine. 
But I'd like to keep GS root distr unattached (even owned by root) and put these libs into some other custom dir. But I can't find a way to configure GS to look for dependencies in my custom dir. PRE_CLASSPATH, CLASSPATH, POST_CLASSPATH don't help. Other useful variables are overwritten by setenv.sh on GS initialization. What I'v done:

```
strings -a /proc/{GSC_PID}/environ | grep tmp
POST_CLASSPATH=/tmp/lib
PRE_CLASSPATH=/tmp/lib
CLASSPATH=/tmp/lib
```

The question is how to configure GS to look for libraries in custom directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here: http://docs.gigaspaces.com/sbp/moving-into-production-checklist.html#runtime-files-location
export GSC_JAVA_OPTIONS="$GSC_JAVA_OPTIONS -Dcom.gs.pu-common=YOUR_DIR_FOR_LIB"